# How to catch Facebook messaging_optins with Azure Bot Channels Registration + Botbuilder SDK?

Tags: node.js, facebook, azure, botframework, facebook-messenger

I've got a chatbot up and running, built using Node.JS Microsoft Bot Framework, and deployed to an Azure server as a Web App, with a Bot Channels Registration resource as the frontend endpoint.

This Bot Channels Registration is connected to Facebook Messenger (via a FB App) - meaning, the webhook for the Facebook App points to `https://facebook.botframework.com/api/v1/bots/<BOT_CHANNELS_REGISTRATION_RESOURCE_NAME>`.

This all works well for normal chat functionality.

However, I'd now like to add an [opt-in checkbox](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/discovery/checkbox-plugin) to a separate web page I have. This checkbox works by pinging FB, which then sends a very specific payload to the already configured bot webhook.

```
{
  "recipient":{
    "id":"<PAGE_ID>"
  },
  "timestamp":<UNIX_TIMESTAMP>,
  "optin":{
    "ref":"<PASS_THROUGH_PARAM>",
    "user_ref":"<UNIQUE_REF_PARAM>"
  }
}
```

My question is this:

How does the Bot Channels Registration receive and handle the above payload? Will it just automatically forward it to the Messaging Endpoint I have configured in the Bot Channels Registration settings? Or will it get stuck, and never reach my actual bot Web App?

Finally, if it *does* reach my normal messages endpoint, how can I handle the specific payload with my `botbuilder.ChatConnector()` listener? Given that my web app code looks like (in essence)

```
var restify = require('restify');
var builder = require('botbuilder');
var dialogues = require('./dialogues');

var chatbot = function (config) {
    var bot = {};
    chatbot.listen = function () {
        var stateStorage = new builder.MemoryBotStorage();

        var connector = new builder.ChatConnector({
            appId: process.env.APP_ID,
            appPassword: process.env.APP_PASSWORD
        });

        bot = new builder.UniversalBot(connector, function (session) {
            session.beginDialog(dialogues.base(bot).name);
        }).set('storage', stateStorage);

        return connector.listen();
    };

    return chatbot;
}

var server = restify.createServer();

// Listen for messages from users 
server.post('/api/messages', chatbot.listen());

server.listen(process.env.port, function () {
    console.log('%s listening to %s', server.name, server.url);
});
```

Thanks!

**EDIT:** I've figured out how to handle the above payload within my messaging endpoint - by adding a `server.pre()` handler to my server, e.g.

```
server.pre(function (req, res, next) {
    if (req.body && req.body.optin_payload_specific_field){
        // handle opt-in payload
    } else {
        return next();
    }
});
```

However, via extra logging lines, it seems the opt-in payload isn't even making it to this endpoint. It seems to be stopped within the Bot Channels Registration. Currently looking for a way to resolve that major roadblock.

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. This gets send to your configured webhook URL, just like everything else.

Comment: @CBroe I've added more details re: where I'm getting stuck - basically, if that payload gets forwarded to my normal web app messages endpoint (which is what's configured in the Bot Channels Registration), how can I modify my botbuilder-based code to handle it (without affecting my normal bot functionality)?

Comment: Also, @CBroe or anyone else interested: after adding extra logging to my Web App, I've learned that this payload does *not* get forwarded by the Bot Channels Registration resource to the configured messaging webhook URL. So it seems this is not as simple as just handling everything within that messaging endpoint on my web app.

Comment: Hi CaptainPlanet! I'm not sure this is something that is currently supported, but I"m looking into it for you!

Comment: @JJ_Wailes awesome, thank you!

Comment: @JJ_Wailes Did you happen to find anything here? I'm currently exploring alternate workarounds, but would much prefer to work within the existing Azure/botbuilder architecture, if there's a way to do so.

Comment: Hi @CaptainPlanet! So, for the bad news: it seems that this is 100% not supported at this time, and is in fact in the list of feature requests for facebook channel. https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/4199 I'm curious about the solution myself, so I am going to continue to look into it, but at this time, the checkbox plugin does not return the proper values, and does not work with the bot framework, with no known workarounds.

Comment: Thanks @JJ_Wailes ! I suspected more or less that this was unsupported, but it's nice to have confirmation. I did find a partial workaround though - see my answer below for details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, per @JJ_Wailes investigation, it seems like this is not a supported feature (in fact, it's a current feature request). See his comments on the original post for more details.

However, I did find a half-workaround to capture the `user_ref` identifier generated by the checkbox_plugin, for those interested:

1) From your external site, follow the steps from the documentation [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/discovery/checkbox-plugin) for sending the initial user_ref to FB. FB will then make a callout to your bot, but per the above, that gets blocked by the Bot Channels Registration piece, so it's ignored.

2) From that same external site, use the `user_ref` to send a message to the user (just using the normal `requests` library). A successful send means that the `user_ref` was properly registered in FB by that step #1 call - a failure means you'll need to repeat step #1 (or use some other error handling flow).

3) After that, the next time the user responds to your bot in FB (as long as you don't send any other messages to them), the message your bot will receive will contain this as part of the payload:

```
{ ...
  channelData:
    { ...
      prior_message:
        { source: 'checkbox_plugin',
          identifier: <user_ref> }
    }
}
```

So I've currently added a check within my `bot.use()`, where if that section is present in the incoming message payload (`session.message.sourceEvent.prior_message`) and the source is "checkbox_plugin", I store the corresponding user_ref in the `session.userData`, and can work from there.

I would *love* to see this feature added into the supported Azure bot stack, but in the meantime hopefully this helps anyone else encountering this (admittedly niche) hurdle.